# HighCarts Pie not showing value in pie label

Tags: highcharts

HighCarts Pie not showing 1 value label if have non-even list of elements in Highcharts.series.data array.

like

```
data: [
  ["1", 14.2],
  ["2", 14.2],
  ["3", 14.2],
  ["4", 14.2],
  ["5", 14.2],
  ["6", 14.2],
  ["7", 14.2]
]
```

or

```
data: [
  ["1", 14.2],
  ["2", 14.2],
  ["3", 14.2],
  ["4", 14.2],
  ["5", 14.2]
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRimQ.jpg)

for example http://jsfiddle.net/370e7w6h/1/

what I do wrong with config, maybe anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

In the plotOptions , change size to 100% from 109% .

```
 plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap:true,
          enabled: true,
          distance: -20,
          color: '#fff',
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '16px',
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        },
        borderWidth: '7px',
        borderColor: '#fff',
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 360,
        center: ['50%', '50%']
      },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/370e7w6h/2/

Comment: Oh ... thanks a lot! Trying so many things what forgot revert this options. Funny moment is when set 108% or 110% works fine ... thank you!